# cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, variables

I have this code

```
filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        int throwid = (int)id;  
        System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
    }
});
```

I try to get the value of `throwid` variable so I create a global variable  `themerowid`  and I do:

```
themerowid = throwid;
```

But I have this error:

> throwid cannot be resolved to a variable

How can I do to get `throwid` value?

The problem is that throwid didn't change value, it always return 0 , I thik that the hole code:

```
filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
           throwid = (int)id;  
          System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
    }
});
```

doesn't be executed, that's why I get 0 all time, there is a mistake in this code.

Comment: define `throwid` outside the listener. Write `int throwid;` before `setOnItemSelectedListener`?

Comment: where's `themerowid` in your code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `thowid` isn't in scope of visibility. Try this:

```
    filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
              themerowid = (int)id;  
              System.out.println( "from onItemselected" + id);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public YOURActivty extend Activty{
    int themerowid;  //<--------------------



      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ...

    }


 public void xYZ() {

    filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    }
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                            int throwid = (int)id;  
                          System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare throwid globally..... then use it...

```
   int throwid
  filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                throwid = (int)id;  
              System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

int throwid;(you shuld keep it as a field, because if you'll keep it as a local variable you have to declare it as final)

```
filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                    throwid = (int)id;  
                  System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
public class testingActivity extends Activity 
{

public int throwid;
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override      
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
  ////YOUR CODE...
          filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                     throwid = (int)id;  
                  System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
            }
        });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `throwId` outside the anonymous class (the listener) like so:

```
public class MyClass extends ... implements ... {
    ...
    ...
    int throwId;

    filethemeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            throwId = (int)id;  
            System.out.println( "from onItemselected" +throwid);
        }
    });
}
```